# page cannot load, BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name ' ' available as request attribute"

Tags: java, spring-mvc, modelattribute

"Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'relationForm' available as request attribute"
I have some issues with the error above, I'll post the important part of the code right here.

Any idea that you guys have is appreciated 
The controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addremoverelation/{caseId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addRelation( @ModelAttribute("relationForm") CaseCompleteForm ccf,
    @PathVariable Long caseId,HttpServletRequest request, BindingResult result) {
    //my code
}
```

The jsp-file

```
<form:form action="${pageRoot}case/addremoverelation/${caseBase.id}"  method="post" id="CaseCompleteForm" modelAttribute="relationForm"> <div>....</div>
```

Comment: Put your `BindingResult` object next to its bean in your controller method. They have to be next to each other.

Comment: Dont realy know what the 'bean' is... but are you saying that I just have to change the order of the argument ? Like this?
public ModelAndView addRelation( @ModelAttribute("relationForm") CaseCompleteForm ccf,BindingResult result
    @PathVariable Long caseId,HttpServletRequest request )

Comment: Yes, try that to start. The `BindingResult` needs to follow the Object instance it's supposed to be representing. Take a look at the Spring documentation, it's important to know what a bean is.

Comment: Solved it! But the problem was none of above.
1, I had made some easy mistakes in the form class. I looked at the link below and found it all out.
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/
2, i forgot to add the following line in the buildPage-function 
map.addAttribute("relationForm", ccf);

Thanks anyway Sotirios for the backup! Your word helped me googling

Comment: You might want to add an answer yourself since you know the details. Might help others later.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not passing the "relationForm" object to the form when the page gets created. Try to add it as a model attribute when you prepare the page.

```
@RenderMapping
public String viewPage(Model model)
{
    if(relForm == null)
    {
        RelationForm relForm = new RelationForm();
        model.addAttribute("relationForm", relForm);
    }

    return "your/view/jsp/file";
}
```

Hope you know what I mean. If you experience any further problems respond in comments, please.